# In LyX, what do I need to do to force bibtex to run?

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

In LyX, if I make changes to code related to my bibliography or citations (e.g. chaining the citation style in BibLaTeX) these changes are (generally) not reflected in my document until I close and reopen my file (or quit and restart LyX). It seems that nether editing my file, nor editing any associated classes, is sufficient to trigger LyX to run bibtex.

Is there something (else, more convenient) I can do to force LyX to run `bibtex`?

Comment: Sometimes an error is sufficient as well: After an error, the next view action produces an updated bibliography and references. It's as if there's something cached that gets flushed on a close/re-open or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts. First, have you tried using two different ways of previewing the output? So if you typically use "pdflatex", try "ps2pdf", or vice versa.

Second, an answer that isn't direct by any means, but explains partly why I've never ran into the same problem you have. Namely, have you considered using [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/support/3.0) + [LyZ](http://www.klubko.net/wp/?page_id=945&lang=en) to handle all your bibtex'ing for your? Whenever I cite a new paper using LyZ, the next time I run any of the previews, the issue is resolved.